# Set Progressbar from another class

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar

I'm trying to set my progressbar from another class but failed. This is my progressbar the class `Upload`.

```
JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
progressBar.setBounds(91, 134, 284, 17);
frame.getContentPane().add(progressBar);
```

I have another class called `Read`. In this class I have a loop that needs to read a file, so I want to set the progress with the iterator `i` from that class. I know that I have to set the minimum and maxium like this:

```
progressBar.setMinimum(0);
progressBar.setMaximum(numRows);
```

And for the value:

```
progressBar.setValue(newValue);
```

How can I set the value for the progressbar so it keeps updating the value of `i`?

Comment: To keep your progressbar updating you need to read your file in another (non-Swing) thread. Best way is to use SwingWorker. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) you can read about.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy I'm not that advanced in Java to understand most of it.

Comment: @Gintoki: `SwingWorker` is the easy way.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your Reader class must have a reference to the component (JProgressBar) in question. I understand that this is already solved.

After that, for reading a file I strongly recommend to use a class extending `javax.swing.SwingWorker`. That pattern allows you to work in background (may be for heavy operations like reading big files) without affecting the AWT thread, so your GUI won't be affected. So, your reader should extend `javax.swing.SwingWorker`.

As a brief resume, it provides a method called `doInBackground` where you should implement the 'heavy' operation and also a method called `process` where it is received the data chunks and you add your own calculations for the progress.

The `process` method is executed in AWT, so you can update any UI Component at this method (so a good point to update your progress bar)

Please, refer to this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You should use SwingWorker for it as described in the [JProgressBar documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html).

This [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) is a thread on which we can add a [propertyChangeListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#addPropertyChangeListener-java.beans.PropertyChangeListener-)

After which we can call [firePropertyChange](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#firePropertyChange-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) to invoke the listener. In the listener we can update the progress bar by calling [setValue()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html#setValue(int)) on it.

Following is a working example of reading a file and updating the progress bar.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class ProgressBar {

    private static final String PROGRESS_PROPERTY_NAME = "progress";
    final static String fileName = "My_file_location";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Progress bar");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        final JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
        progressBar.setMinimum(0);
        progressBar.setMaximum(100);
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);

        panel.add(progressBar);


        JButton button = new JButton("Start reading");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ReadFiletask task = new ReadFiletask(fileName);
                 task.addPropertyChangeListener(
                 new PropertyChangeListener() {
                     public  void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {

                         if (PROGRESS_PROPERTY_NAME.equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                             progressBar.setValue((Integer)evt.getNewValue());
                         }
                     }
                 });

                 task.execute();
            }
        });
        panel.add(button);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static class ReadFiletask extends SwingWorker<Boolean, Integer> {
        String fileName;
        public ReadFiletask (String fileName) {
            this.fileName = fileName;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Started reading");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];//1mb
            InputStream is = null;
            try {
                Path file = Paths.get(fileName);
                long fileSize = Files.size(file);
                is = Files.newInputStream(file, StandardOpenOption.READ);
                int readLen = -1;
                int readCounter = 0;
                while((readLen = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    readCounter += readLen;

                    int percentDone = (int)( (readCounter * 100.0) / fileSize);
                    System.out.println("done : " + percentDone);

                    /*Most important part is here */

                    firePropertyChange(PROGRESS_PROPERTY_NAME, 0, percentDone);
                }

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if(is != null) {
                    try {
                        is.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Finished");
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I had to add String PROGRESS_PROPERTY_NAME = UploadGUI.PROGRESS_PROPERTY_NAME; or it would give me an error because the variable is not recognized(UploadGUI being the class where the bar is). The bar also jumps from 0 to 100 when the task is done, but I see the % displayed in the console. Do you have an idea why that is?

Comment: Try for large files, for small files it may run too quickly.

Comment: It should have worked with the SwingWorker also as it's Runnable instance it can directly be passed to a Thread. Swing is just making some things easier for us.